# Sorting using Jquery with PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Following is my Jquery code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(
            function() {
                jQuery("#document-list-1").sortable({
                    update : function () {
                        serial = jQuery('#document-list-1').sortable('serialize');
                        jQuery.ajax({
                        url: "/?module=website_documents&action=reorder_website_document_by_dragdrop&website_id=18374",
                        type: "post",
                        data: serial,
                        error: function(){
                            alert("there is an error with AJAX");
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
        jQuery(document).ready(
                function() {
                    jQuery("#documentChildList").sortable({
                        update : function () {
                            serial = jQuery('#documentChildList').sortable('serialize');
                            jQuery.ajax({
                            url: "/?module=website_documents&action=reorder_website_document_by_dragdrop&website_id=18374",
                            type: "post",
                            data: serial,
                            error: function(){
                                alert("there is an error with AJAX");
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
```

HTML code:

```
<ul id="document-list-1">
  <li><img src="images/move.jpg">Test1
   <ul id="documentChildList">
      <li><img src="images/move.jpg">test2</li>
      <li><img src="images/move.jpg">test3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

For parent category sorting is working fine. But for child category, in IE8, when I click on it, its image i.e. move.jpg gets shifted to right side and also the whole list along with parent category moves up and down.

If I remove the jQuery code of 'document-list-1' then sorting of child category also working fine but then parent category sorting is not working.

Don't know what is going wrong.

Comment: Can you replicate on [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.com)?

Comment: Following is the URL where you can see the issue:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/16K3w-w-6lrHdkCdxC88aYoblENq2k4gXoJzSrHyJurM/edit

Comment: An Image? it's like trying to solve a puzzle with my eyes closed.

Comment: I am unable to replicate it on JSFiddle that's why uploaded an image. Are you not able to see that image? Plz let me know....

Comment: I can see image but it's nothing I can do ..

Comment: ohh ok...Actually, I want to sort the nested listing. For simple sorting I make it work but for nested not able to do that. Can you please guide me how can I do it?